# Unlock the Funds in the Script with CSL

Tags: plutus, cardano-serialization-lib

I'm building a transaction that using UTXO at script as the input.
Seem I signed enough `vkey`, perhaps include `transactionWitnessSet.set_plutus_scripts`.

Finally, i got this error `Script inputs not supported yet`.

Does anyone know work-around solution? ref: https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/blob/master/rust/src/tx_builder.rs#L95